# NodeJS unable to bind to an Azure internal port

Tags: node.js, azure, iisnode

I'm trying to get NodeJS to listen to an **internal** endpoint on Azure.

I've got the following set-up.

1. I've created an internal endpoint for port 8082 via ServiceDefinition.
2. In my server.js I have 2 http servers

   `server.listen(process.env.port); // External
   server.listen(8082); // Internal`
3. The external port is bound by IISNode and correctly responds to a request.
4. However the internal port fails with

   `Error: 
   listen EACCES
   at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
   at listen (net.js:1061:10)
   at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)`

If I change the port to say 8083 then there is no error.

Does anyone know why Node is unable to bind to an Azure internal port?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the internal endpoint?  Can you copy that portion of your csdef?

Comment: are you using cloud services (web role) or azure websites?

Comment: @kwill, I was using an HTTP endpoint. I got an answer from the IISNode people that I should be using a TCP endpoint. (Seems a bit obvious now). Let me try that out.

Comment: @AmitApple it's a cloud service.

Comment: Correct, TCP endpoint.  HTTP endpoints setup a binding with IIS which is why your Node server couldn't also bind to that same port.  TCP endpoints just setup firewall rules but leave the binding up to you.